# Direct connect mysql server without php in swift- 4(code) iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am trying to connect to MySqlServer by code in swift directly without php file.
Is there any way to do the same? we have enterprise  application where we need to direct connect with mysql db

Comment: Mobile apps generally connect to an API, not directly to a database.

Comment: We need to connect to db directly . that is required

Comment: can you explain what you want?

Comment: We need to fetch data from database (sqlserver) by querying so that we can prefill the details of the user if they already exists in the db - that is required to be fetched directly not through the API

Comment: it's not possible. you can use firebase database instead of MySqlServer then its possible.

Comment: It's possible using my sql client

Comment: how It's possible?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49409913/4869734

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using mySqlClient.We need to enter host name, user, password and db_name and connect to db. Using this we can query db directly and fetch data therein

Comment: What mySqlClient are you referring? I have never found any reliable enough mySqlClients for iOS and really want to know what client you have found.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one way to connect with database without using php. 
use firebase database. No need for server side coding .. you can get and set data using swift. it looks just like you are posting data in mobile database.