# Setting up URL for a webservice

Tags: php, ios, swift, database, mobile-development

I'm trying to plan out a mobile application (iOS) that has to connect to a remote database. After doing some research, I found that I'd have to connect to the DB by using a PHP framework.

I learned this from reading multiple articles, but I specifically got my information from this stack overflow question: [How to connect mysql with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468868/how-to-connect-mysql-with-swift)

What I'm confused on is how I can set up the URL for the web service. How is this accomplished? Is this some sort of server you pay for? Can you set the URL to be the same as your remote database server?

For example, in the last piece of code in the linked stack overflow answer, the user had:

```
  //URL to our web service
    let URL_SAVE_TEAM = "http://192.168.1.103/MyWebService/api/createteam.php"
```

What exactly is this?

I think I am misunderstanding a concept here.

Comment: You still have to read a lot. `Swift` and `PHP` are totally different and they don't have the same way to connect to a database. In addition, it is not important to only connect to MySQL if you don't want to. You may use Firebase for example or use a different DB system.

Comment: @MerianosNikos This question i have linked explains how to connect to an already existing, remote database. This cannot be done using swift which is why they explained the need to use PHP. Swift will call the PHP file which will then communicate with the database. I know that swift and PHP are different.

Comment: @MerianosNikos Firebase will not help me - my app needs to send and retrieve information to a company's database that already exists on sqlServer

Comment: ***What exactly is this?*** That is a URL within the local network. Meaning within the router in that persons home.

Comment: @Andreas - How do I make this URL to use in my own application?

Answer (score 0):

"192.168.1.103" or "google.com" identifies a server (PC) on the local network or on the internet. It is either your own PC or a rented one from some hosting provider. I would suggest the following steps:

1. Identify what platform do you want to use as your remote database. I see you are quoting some text about mysql, but there are a lot more choices. You could look into noSQL databases like CouchDB or you could use just a file with text hosted somewhere.
2. Based on the platform you can check where you could buy hosting for your database. I could suggest looking into Amazon AWS, they can provide you a free Linux PC, where you can host MYSQL server or CouchDB server or even a simple file server to host your data. You can also first try to install corresponding server to your local machine (e.g. to the same one running iOS emulator) and try to connect using http://localhost address (url).
3. Connect to the corresponding server from your iOS App and write logic to read, update, create, delete data if it is needed.

Comment: I have a remote database already implemented and being used by the company that my app needs to access - the platform of this database is sqlServer. Why would I look into other databases? I have to use the one at my company so I'm confused by that suggestion

Comment: Ok, it seems I completely misunderstood you. The URL you are talking about seems to point to a step in the middle — API. Basically, Swift connects to API server, and then API server talks with the database. Do you know if you have it? If we are talking about MySQL it is much easier to have this middle step, than to write swift code to directly communicate with MySQL server from an App. Sounds logical to install this API server somewhere inside your company network in case you don’t have it. One popular PHP example of such API is called mysqli.

Comment: Hmm I'm still a bit lost. My company's database is located on a server. (is that what you're asking?) Since I don't need to make a new database, could I just make a PHP file that creates a connection to my database's server? and then my swift code calls the PHP file?

Comment: Technically it is possible to host PHP file (or other API solution) on the same server where the database is located. But I don’t know if it will work for you. I think it is a good idea to speak with someone responsible for the server. You don’t have to use PHP as API, there are other choices. It is possible, some API is already in place for an existing MySQL server and can be used to communicate with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions so far- What API could i use with an existing server if not PHP? is that not a secure/recommended route to take?

Comment: Personally, I write my own APIs to connect with database using Swift on the server. I could suggest Vapor framework for it, they have MySQL support.

In the quoted thread I saw suggestion to use SailsJS on Node. It was said, it takes 5 minutes to make an API from a MySQL database. http://sailsjs.org

Comment: how do you write your API's? I'd like to write my own as well

Comment: I wrote a swift webserver using Kitura (but I plan to switch to Vapor, because IBM doesn't develop Kitura anymore). The server is hosted on a dedicated Linux system (Ubuntu officially supports Swift). It receives REST API http requests from apps, retracts data from the database and sends it back to app in JSON format.
There are a lot of tutorials on how to create REST API with Vapor.